# Endpoints of the $x$ of the function $y=g(x)$ used for the change of variable - Probability density function

Tags: probability, density-function, change-of-variable

I have the following PDF:

\begin{equation}
f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2 \, \sqrt{1 - x}} &\text{if } 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

whose domain is $\mathbb{R}$, and I've $Y = X \, (1 - X)$.

I'd like to know if:

$$
y = g(x) = x \, (1 - x) \quad \forall \, x \in \mathbb{R}
$$

or if:

\begin{equation}
y = g(x) =
\begin{cases}
x \, (1 - x) = x - x^2 &\text{if } 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

or if the above two $g(x)$ are equivalent.

---

EDIT: I'd like to know also if the determination of the different intervals of $f(g(x))$ should be done before, during or after the writing of the $f(g(x))$ pieces.

I need an explanation on how to define the endpoints of $g(x)$.

Comment: The $\text{pdf}$ being zero outside $[0,1]$, the definition of $g$ there does not matter.

Comment: I would say that $0\leq x\color{red}<1$, since for $x=1$ the pdf $f_X(x)$ is not defined.

Comment: I believe $y=g(x)=x(1-x) \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ is correct option. The fact that PDF in some intervals is equal to zero does not influence domain if there are no additional restrictions.

Comment: If you don't give a reply, then your question leads to nowhere.

Comment: Hello @callculus42 thank you for your precisation. Which question would you like me to answer?